# Trouble with C++ Classes and Functions - Function to print out a 2D array

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to make a Battleship game in C++ and I've been having a huge nightmare trying to get my classes set up the way I wanted them to be. Bellow I've included some code as well as more information about how I'm trying to program the game.

There are three classes and header files: Game.cpp, Ships.cpp and Player.cpp as well as their corresponding header files Game.h, Ships.h and Player.h. Ships and Player are only there to store the information regarding those items where as I want the bulk of functions to be associated with the Game class.

**Currently the only way I can display my rudimentary game board is by initializing it in my main() and then using it as a local variable. I want to put that "print" function into my game.cpp.**

I've had several goes at it all which is why you'll see random bits of code all over the place. I feel like once I get it down once I'll have more confidence and be able to replicate other classes and function.

The functions I've identified that I need for my game so far are as follows:
Clear //clears game board
Show //shows the game board
countNumberOfShips //counts how many ships there are ie when 0 ships remain you lose or win depending on who is at 0.
setShips // allows you to place your ships and randomly places computer's ships.
attack // controls the attack sequences, is responsible for shoot,hit miss, sink.

main.cpp

```
#include "game.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int board3[10][10] = {
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
};

string name;
int option1;
bool playerWin = false;
string type;


int main()

{


cout << "Hello, welcome to battleship" << endl;
Game mygame;
//mygame.displayBoard();

for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{ 
    for(int j=0; j < 10; j++)
    { 
        cout <<  board3[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}



/**Game go;
cout << "Welcome, please enter your name: "; cin >> name;
cout <<"Are you a player or a computer?"; cin >> type;
Player newPlayer(name, player);
go.addPlayer(newPlayer);

cout << "Okay " << name << "! Are you ready to lose?" << endl;


cout << "hello world" << endl; //game function goes here

**/

system("pause");
return 0;


};
```

game.h

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

   #include "Player.h"
   #include "Ships.h"
   #include <vector>

   class Game {
public:
    Game();
    ~Game();
    //void addPlayer(Player newPlayer);
    void displayBoard();
    //void addShip(Ships newShip);
private:

};

#endif
```

game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"
#include <vector>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Game::Game() {
    cout << "Hello Mr Rabbit!" << endl;
}

Game::~Game() {
}

void Game::displayBoard()

{
    int gameBoard[10][10];
    for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
    { 
        for(int j=0; j < 10; j++)
        { 
            cout <<  gameBoard[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a clear question so that we know what help you are asking for?

Comment: @ArunA.S  Thanks for replying! I've edited the title and highlighted my question in my OP. Is that better and easier to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a brief glimpse over your code, it seems you may want to include your gameBoard array as a variable within your Game class. From there you could then create two separate 'Game' objects, one for the player and the other for the computer.  Then you would have 2 separate gameBoard arrays that you could manipulate by using the . operator like so: playerGame.gameBoard[i][j] or computerGame.gameBoard[i][j].

Hope this helps!

Edit: Since you've clarified your question, and based on what I've already mentioned. You could then rewrite your displayBoard function to operate on the gameBoard array of the Game object. The for loop method you are already using will still work, as long as you remove what would then be a re-declaration of gameBoard.

Once again, hope this helps!

Comment: Yep it does, I have tried but I haven't really found much success with attempting that. Is this what I'm meant to do? So in Game.h, under Private: Initialize a variable called gameBoard[10][10]

Comment: Correct, from what I can discern.

Comment: So I've initialized the gameBoard variable in game.h, and I've called my function in main().cpp myGame.displayBoard(); and it does output 100 values except the're like -858993460 could this just be a memory address or something?

Comment: Though you may already know that you'd have to write additional functions within the Game class to manipulate the gameBoard, and would not be able to use the Game.gameBoard syntax to access the data contained therein within main.

Comment: @Thanks boz. 

so initialized the array in my game.h and set the parameters to [10][10]. Then I made a new function called setBoard. Which sets all the values in gameBoard to 0 and I then called my other function displayBoard which pints out the entire array which is 10x10 of 0's.

Comment: Sounds like you're ready to move on to the next step of your game, then!

Comment: Just quickly, how do I make two separate objects of the game board. I want one to be for the player the other to be for the computer. I have a working function which randomly places ships on the board but I want to apply it only to the computer's board.